# Using filepaths as global variables in Python

Tags: python-3.x, import, global-variables

I have a file `global_vars.py` that contains file paths saved as variables:

```
from pandas import Timestamp
final_vol_path = 'datasets/final_vols.csv'
final_price_path = 'datasets/final_prices.csv'
final_start_date = Timestamp('2017-01-01')
```

with other variables written in a similar fashion. However, the functions that I'm using to read in the data throw a `FileNotFoundError` when attempting to do the following in `file1.py`:

```
import scripts.global_vars as gv
read_data(gv.final_vol_path, gv.final_price_path) # throws FileNotFoundError
read_data('datasets/final_vols.csv', 'datasets/final_prices.csv') # this passes
```

Additionally, I've checked the file paths, and have gotten the following:

```
gv.final_vol_path == 'datasets/final_vols.csv' # returns True
gv.final_price_path == 'datasets/final_prices.csv' # returns True
```

Moreover, the pandas `Timestamp` object is processed without any problems.

Is there any explanation for why the `FileNotFoundError` is being thrown when attempting to access the file path as a variable from `global_vars.py`, but is not thrown when the actual string is passed in?

EDIT: The overall directory structure is as follows:

```
working_dir
L file1.py
    L scripts
       L global_vars.py
    L datasets
       L final_vols.csv
       L final_prices.csv
```

EDIT 2: I added in a try-catch block to ensure the rest of the function doesn't break, not sure if that has affected the traceback, but here's what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\runpy.py", line 
184, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\Ananth\Anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\Scripts\nose2.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\main.py", line 306, in discover
        return main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\main.py", line 100, in __init__
        super(PluggableTestProgram, self).__init__(**kw)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\unittest\main.py", line 93, in __init__
        self.parseArgs(argv)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\main.py", line 133, in parseArgs
        self.createTests()
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\main.py", line 258, in createTests
        self.testNames, self.module)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\loader.py", line 69, in loadTestsFromNames
        for name in event.names]
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\loader.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
        for name in event.names]
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\loader.py", line 84, in loadTestsFromName

        result = self.session.hooks.loadTestsFromName(event)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\events.py", line 224, in __call__
        result = getattr(plugin, self.method)(event)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\plugins\loader\testcases.py", line 56, in loadTestsFromName
        result = util.test_from_name(name, module)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\util.py", line 106, in test_from_name
        parent, obj = object_from_name(name, module)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\nose2\util.py", line 117, in object_from_name
        module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
      File "C:\Users\Ananth\Desktop\Modules\PortfolioVARModule\tests\test_simulation.py", line 24, in <module>
        gv.test_start_date)
      File "C:\Users\Ananth\Desktop\Modules\PortfolioVARModule\scripts\prep_data.py", line 119, in read_data
        priceDF = pd.read_csv(pricepath).dropna()
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
        return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 389, in _read
        parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
        self._make_engine(self.engine)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
        self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
      File "c:\users\ananth\anaconda3\envs\analytics-cpu\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
        self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
      File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4184)
      File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8449)
    FileNotFoundError: File b'datasets/corn_price.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: What happens if you use the full path ?

Comment: what does `print gv.final_vol_path` returns ?
I'm guessing a unicode problem.

Comment: @PedroLobito I've tried specifying the absolute path, and it still throws the same `FileNotFoundError` even though I can see the file right there in the directory. Not entirely sure why.

Comment: @Trolldejo `> print(gv.final_vol_path) 
                   datasets/final_vols.csv `

Comment: May you copy past the traceback from the FileNotFoundError ?

Comment: I see you put parenthesis calling your print in the comment, if you're using python3 would be nice to tag your question as so.

Comment: @Trolldejo updated the flag, and added the traceback.

Comment: The traceback is not reflecting a FileNotFoundError..?

Comment: @Trolldejo my bad, updated again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is the addition of the letter b in front of your file's path.
You get the b because you encoded to utf-8.
Try:

```
read_data(str(gv.final_vol_path,'utf-8'), str(gv.final_price_path, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: This does not work, the error simply changes to `FileNotFoundError: File b'atasets/final_vols.csv' does not exist `

Comment: Yeah I noticed as I posted it, I updated my answer tho.